# Alcohol limitations crossing into Canada from U.S

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, alcohol

I'm planning a trip to Canada from the U.S. this summer and would like to bring some craft beer to share with family members who live there. How much will Canada customs allow me to bring into the country? Is it possible to pay duty on any excess that I try to bring across? FYI, I'm traveling by car, and would like to bring around 6 cases of beer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are of legal age in  the US and Canada, they have a site listing [all the restrictions](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/atl-lat-eng.html).

It's not very much, unfortunately, limiting you to around 8.5L or roughly 24 cans.

However, their [alcohol specific page](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/publications/pub/bsf5056-eng.html#s2x13) which also says the same thing, does mention that it may vary by province, but I wouldn't expect it to vary much.

*added*

Alcohol is ONE of the categories that you can bring in duty free, up to the specified limit (others are things such as tobacco products).

It IS possible to pay duty if you wish to import more, but it may be easier to just buy them in Canada, depending on the location and type of beer.

Comment: Note that hose restrictions are the *duty and tax free limits*, not import limits. If you have more you just declare them and pay the assessed taxes. Bit more complicated if you have commercial quantities, 6 cases hardly qualifies as commercial quantities.

Comment: Assuming one is willing to pay additional tax, you can bring an additional 5 cases of beer into Ontario with you. These import limits vary by province it seems, and in my case it would be Ontario. http://hellolcbo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/278/~/importing%3A-importation-limits The craft beer I'm bringing is unlikely to be available in Ontario, so it might be worth the additional fee.